# Find all groups of 9

Tags: javascript, regex

I am learning JS regex, so I am thinking about this example string `99s999s99s99`. 
Now I want to find all number sequences within this string. I tried the following:

```
var s = /(\d+)/g;
var a = '99s999s99s99';
s.exec(a);

var s = /(\d+)/;
var a = '99s999s99s99';
s.exec(a);
```

but both are producing the following output:
`[ '99', '99', index: 0, input: '99s999s99s99' ]`

How to find all the groups of `9`s?

Comment: did you provide the `g` (global) flag?

Comment: use    global flag `/\d+/g`

Comment: With `g` as well the answer is same.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is fine (although it will match other digits, not 9's only like your title suggests), but you're using [RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) when you want [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

`'99s999s99s99'.match( /(\d+)/g )` returns the array:

```
["99", "999", "99", "99"]
```

`RegExp.prototype.exec` must be [called repeatedly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches) using the same RegExp to find all the matches, otherwise it only finds one.

Comment: I was using 'exec()' method as prescribed in JS: The Good Parts.

Comment: @RajatSaxena They are both valid functions to use but they have different behaviour. You could use exec with a loop as per the last link in my answer, but I believe `match` will suit you better.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code and link for demo:

> Code:

```
var str = "99s999s99s99";
var pattern = /\d+/g;
var result = str.match(pattern);
console.log(result);
```

> Execution:

```js
var str = "99s999s99s99";
var pattern = /\d+/g;
var result = str.match(pattern);
console.log(result);
```

> Demo Link: [JS BIN](https://jsbin.com/ceyekabara/edit?js,console,output)